# Unable to print ansible_failed_task.name in rescue block

Tags: ansible

Following is the piece of code, which is retrieving list of local zones and trying to enter rescue block if any one of the local zones is not in RUNNING state.

But the rescue block is failing, at 'Check if the zones are in running state'

Expectation is to send an email with the task name. But it is working well with other failed tasks.Can anyone please guide?

FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/misc/test1404.yml': line 23, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n     rescue:\n      - name: Sending an e-mail from Ansible controller node\n        ^ here\n"}

```
    - '{{ host }}'
  tasks:
   - block:
      - name: Retrieve list of local zones
        shell: /usr/sbin/zoneadm list | grep -v global   
        register: lzones      
        tags: 
          - local_zone_list
      - debug:
           msg: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{lzones.stdout_lines}}"

      - name: Check if the zones are in running state
        shell: /usr/sbin/zoneadm list | grep -v global | grep "{{ item }}" | awk '{print$3}'
        register: status
        with_items: "{{lzones.stdout_lines}}"
        failed_when: status.stdout.find('running') == -1


        < few other tasks>

     rescue:
      - name: Sending an e-mail from Ansible controller node
        mail:
            host: localhost
            port: 25
            to: xyz@abc.com
            subject: Reboot Failed
            body: Reboot FAILED at TASK - {{ ansible_failed_task.name }} with ERROR {{ ansible_failed_result }}
        delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you were to show us what line 23 is of `/etc/ansible/playbooks/misc/test1404.yml` since there is no way we can guess which of those lines is number 23 in your file

Answer (score 2):

*Well that was an absolutely fascinating rabbit hole.*

Because in ansible jinja2 templates are [rendered **recursively**](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.6/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py#L522), when it tries to render the failed message, which contains the failed template, it tries to re-render the *failed template again*, re-causing the error

This appears to be impacting you by the inclusion of the `ansible_failed_task` variable, since -- *inexplicably* -- it appears to be safe to include `ansible_failed_result` in the body

As best I can tell by experimenting with ansible 2.9.6, one must determine if it is possible to safely output the `a*_task` flavor variable before touching it, because I was wholly unable to find any combination of `| string` or `|regex_replace` or **anything** that allowed jinja2 to touch that variable so long as it contains the bogus variable reference:

```yaml
  - block:
    - debug:
        msg: this explodes {{ nope_not_a_var }}

    rescue:
    - set_fact:
        is_undefined_error: '{{ "undefined variable" in ansible_failed_result.msg }}'

    - name: variable is unsafe version
      debug:
        msg: >-
          failed task action has an undefined variable in the task,
          so we cannot show you the task, but here is the result: {{ ansible_failed_result }}
      when: is_undefined_error

    - name: variable is safe to output version
      debug:
        msg: Reboot FAILED at TASK - {{ ansible_failed_task.name }} with ERROR {{ ansible_failed_result }}
      when: not is_undefined_error
```

It may be safe to inline that test of `"..." in ansible_failed_result.msg` into the `when:` lines directly, but since it (**should**) produce the same answer both times, there's no really good reason to evaluate it twice

---

This appears to me to be an ansible bug, but I don't have the emotional energy to take it up with their community -- however, I encourage you to [file a bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22ansible_failed_task%22) with them